# Service Routing Table works in IIS7 but not IIS6?

Tags: wcf, iis-7, routes, .net-4.0, iis-6

I've got a WCF service that uses a Global.asax file to activate my services. So, my deployed virtual directory on my deployment box looks like

web.config
global.asax
 - which contains Services.dll and Services.pdb

the Services.dll is the compiled bits of my Service.svc and Service.svc.cs files.

How do I get this setup to work in IIS6? My Global.asax looks like:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes();
    }

    private void RegisterRoutes()
    {
        WebServiceHostFactory factory = new WebServiceHostFactory();
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("MyService", factory, typeof(MyService)));
    }
}
```

Any ideas? This works in IIS7 such that I can navigate to http://server/MyService/...

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Unfortunately in IIS6, you need to decide on an extension to use so that your url is http://server/MyService.extension. Then you need to register that extension in IIS6 to be handled by ASP.NET.

We use .mvc, so our urls look like http://server/MyService.mvc. We're moving to IIS7 shortly so we kinda just stuck to that for now, so there may be a better way.